# Android service restarts, but application does not

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am developing an application that sends over a webservice information about the last dialed number, call status, and duration of the call.

The application works perfectly fine, but when the device closes the application the android service does restart but the activity does not.

The way I am sure about that is that I have Toasts when the service is started: "Servicio TRUCKA iniciado" and "Servicio TRUCKA creado" tell me that the service has been created and started.

And when the information is sent to the webservice I have toasts saying: "Enviando información..." and "Información enviada."

But when the application is closed (via the android task manager that automatically closes apps) the messages from the service "Servicio TRUCKA iniciado" and "Servicio TRUCKA creado" do appear, but the toasts from the information sent part do not.

I hope someone can help me and tell what am I doing wrong? :)

This is my Activity:

```
package com.trucka.llamadasdrivers;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import com.trucka.llamadasdrivers.R;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.*;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class ActividadLlamadasDrivers extends Activity {
    TextView txtInformacion = null;
    TextView txtDetalles = null;
    TextView tv = null;
    // Comunicación con el webservice.
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://truckanet.com/MensajeOperador";
    // private final String URL =
    // "http://192.168.10.94/MensajeOperador/MensajeOperador.asmx";
    private final String URL = "http://200.76.187.148/MensajeOperador/MensajeOperador.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://truckanet.com/MensajeOperador/ActualizarFede";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "ActualizarFede";
    private String TAG = "TRUCKA_DRIVERS";
    private String resultado;
    String phNumber = null;
    String callType = null;
    String callDate = null;
    DateFormat shortFecha = null;
    DateFormat shortDF = null;
    Date callDayTime = null;
    Date fin = null;
    String fechaLlamada1 = null;
    String fechaLlamada2 = null;
    String callDuration = null;
    String dir = null;
    public String tolo = null;
    String imei = null;
    String comentario = null;
    String fechaRegistro = null;
    String insercion = null;
    String fechaInicio = null;
    String fechaFin = null;
    String estadoLlamada = null;
    int reinicios = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_llamadas_drivers);

        if (!ServicioLlamadas.isRunning()) {
            reinicios ++;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(reinicios) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(ActividadLlamadasDrivers.this,
                    ServicioLlamadas.class);
            ActividadLlamadasDrivers.this.startService(in);
            TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(),
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txvEstadoServicio);
            txtInformacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_call);
            txtDetalles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_call2);
        }

    }

    class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean telefonoLlamando = false;
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                // phone ringing
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // active
                //getCallDetails();
                telefonoLlamando = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Enviando información...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                // run when class initial and phone call ended, 
                // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Información enviada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (telefonoLlamando) {


                    // restart app
                    getCallDetails();

                    telefonoLlamando = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    // Obtener la fecha actual del teléfono.
    public long getTodayTimestamp() {
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(new Date());

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(Calendar.YEAR, c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        c2.set(Calendar.MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        return c2.getTimeInMillis();
    }

    // Obtener el detalle de las llamadas con la fecha actual.
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void getCallDetails() {
        String timestamp = String.valueOf(getTodayTimestamp());
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                CallLog.Calls.DATE + ">= ?", new String[] { timestamp }, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append("Bitácora de llamadas :");
        Integer contador = 0;
        // while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        // managedCursor.moveToFirst();
        managedCursor.moveToLast();
        contador = contador + 1;
        phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        shortFecha = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        shortDF = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
        callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        fechaLlamada1 = shortDF.format(callDayTime);
        fechaLlamada2 = shortFecha.format(callDayTime);
        callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "Saliente";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "Entrante";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "Perdida";
            break;
        }

        imei = mngr.getDeviceId();
        comentario = dir;
        fechaRegistro = fechaLlamada2;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        String ahorita = df.format(callDayTime);
        fechaInicio = ahorita.toString();
        // fechaFin =
        // df.format(callDayTime.setSeconds(callDayTime.getSeconds()+5));

        insercion = "DECLARE @claveDriver INT, @nombreDriver VARCHAR(max), @evento VARCHAR(max), @duracion int, @inicial varchar(max) "
                + "SET @claveDriver = (SELECT cve_tra FROM SISTEMA.dbo.TELEFONOS WHERE IMEI_SIM = '"
                + mngr.getDeviceId()
                + "') "
                + "SET @nombreDriver = (SELECT nombre FROM SISTEMA.dbo.TELEFONOS WHERE IMEI_SIM = '"
                + mngr.getDeviceId()
                + "') "
                + "SET @duracion = "
                + managedCursor.getString(duration)
                + "SET @evento = '(LOG) Llamada "
                + dir
                + ". Duración ' + CONVERT(varchar, @duracion, 103) + ' segundos al número: "
                + managedCursor.getString(number)
                + "' "
                // + "SET @duracion = " + callDuration
                + " SET @inicial = '"
                + fechaInicio
                + "'"
                + "INSERT INTO bitacora.dbo.registroDellamadasOperadores (fechacreacion,fecha_fin,fecha_inicio,idMobil,Tractor,Nom_tra,Cve_tra,FechaRegistro,Evento) "
                + " VALUES('"
                + fechaInicio
                + "', DATEADD(SECOND,@duracion,@inicial),'"
                + fechaInicio
                + "','"
                + mngr.getDeviceId()
                + "','',@nombreDriver,@claveDriver,current_timestamp,@evento)";
        AsyncCallWS tareaEnviarABD = new AsyncCallWS();
        tareaEnviarABD.execute();

        sb.append("\nNúmero de teléfono:--- " + phNumber
                + " \nTipo de llamada:--- " + dir + " \nFecha de llamada:--- "
                + fechaLlamada2 + " " + fechaLlamada1
                + " \nDuración en segundos:--- " + callDuration
                + " \nDispositivo actual:--" + mngr.getDeviceId());
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");

        // }
        txtDetalles.setText(sb);
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            InsertarLlamada(insercion);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
            txtInformacion.setText("Información enviada");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            txtInformacion.setText("Enviando información...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

        public void InsertarLlamada(String insercion) {
            // Creamos la solicitud
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            // Propiedades que contienen los valores
            PropertyInfo propiedades = new PropertyInfo();

            propiedades.setName("insercion");
            propiedades.setValue(insercion);
            propiedades.setType(String.class);
            // Agregamos las propiedades
            request.addProperty(propiedades);
            // Creamos el envelope
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            // ponemos la salida SOAP
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            // Creamos la llamada HTTP
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
                // Invocamos el servicio
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                // Obtenemos la respuesta
                Object response = envelope.getResponse();
                // Asignamos el resultado de la consulta
                resultado = response.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                resultado = e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BootReceiver class:

```
package com.trucka.llamadasdrivers;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ActividadLlamadasDrivers.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Llamadas service:

```
package com.trucka.llamadasdrivers;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServicioLlamadas extends Service {

    private static ServicioLlamadas instance = null;

    public static boolean isRunning() {
        return instance != null;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio TRUCKA creado",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio TRUCKA destruído",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        instance = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servicio TRUCKA iniciado",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lanzarNotificacion();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    void lanzarNotificacion() {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        // Configuramos la notificacion
        Notification notif = new Notification(
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_agenda, "Servicio TRUCKA",
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Configuramos el Intent
        Context contexto = ServicioLlamadas.this;
        CharSequence titulo = "Notificación Servicio TRUCKA";
        CharSequence descripcion = "Registro habilitado.";

        // Intent que se abrira al clickear la notificacion
        PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, null,
                0);
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(contexto, titulo, descripcion, contIntent);
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notif.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notManager.notify(1, notif);
    }
}
```

And manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trucka.llamadasdrivers"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.trucka.llamadasdrivers.ActividadLlamadasDrivers"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.trucka.llamadasdrivers.ServicioLlamadas"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Human stupidity has no limits.
My actines where not in the service